# Is this function an increasing function?

Tags: calculus

If this $ f: x \rightarrow\frac{x} {\sqrt{x-1}} / Df = ]1, +\infty[$ an increasing function over $[2, +\infty[$, then why $ f(5) \leq 5$?

Comment: What is "$+00$"?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited

Comment: What does $f(5) \leq 5$ have to do with anything?  $g(x) = .001 x$ is increasing and has that property... for all numbers.

Comment: "increasing function" means that if $x\leq y$, then $f(x)\leq f(y)$ (or that if $x\lt y$ then $f(x)\lt f(y)$, depending on your precise definition). It does **not** mean that $f(x)\gt x$ for all $x$.

Comment: Sorry, I am just confused! you re right!

Answer (score 1):

An increasing function is defined as a function whose values never decrease when the graph is sketched from left to right . This implies that the derivative (rate of change) has to be positive at all points in the domain that you are analyzing. The derivative of your function is  $(x-2)/(2(x-1)^{1.5})$. This means that your function is increasing for all the values in your domain, even though the rate of change is getting smaller. Note that the function can map your domain to smaller values and still be increasing such as $0.5x$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x-1}}=x(x-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}},$ then $f'(x)=(x-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{x(x-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2}$ by the product rule.
$$(x-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{x(x-1)^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{2}\geq0$$
$$\iff 1\geq\frac{x}{2(x-1)}$$
provided that $x>1$ (since then we can divide through by $(x-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ since $x-1\neq 0$). It is clear that $1\geq\frac{x}{2(x-1)}$ if $x\geq 2$, so $f$ is non-decreasing in $[2,\infty)$, since its derivative is non-negative in that interval, and strictly increasing in $(2,\infty)$, since its derivative is positive in that interval. As for why $f(5)<5$, the fact that $f$ is increasing does not imply that $f(x)\geq x$.